# Do all even-number square matrices have at least one eigenvector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My instructor says that all odd number matrices, like a 5*5 matrix, have at least one eigenvector. Do even number matrices have the same property?

Comment: Please add what your thoughts are about the question. As it stands the question doesn't fit the rules described in the [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: the question you should ask is why do the odd-sized real matrices have at least one eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If you mean *real* matrices, consider the matrix of a $90$-degree rotation in the plane.

Try to see how this generalizes to matrices of all even dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean an eigenvector associated with a Real eigenvalue. By parity: Complex roots come in pairs, so that if $z$ is a root of $f$, then so is $z^{-}$, its Complex conjugate. This means that the characteristic polynomial associated with an $(n+1) \times (n+1)-$ matrix will have at least one Real root and a Real eigenvector associated with it.